# how to make tomcat 6 running mulitple domain with non ROOT application name

Tags: tomcat6

I am trying to run multiple domain on a tomcat 6 on a linux server.

I got 404 Errors when I follow the steps here
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

Here is the conf

```
server.xml
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="a.mydomain.com">
    <Host name="a.mydomain.com" appBase="aapps" autoDeploy="true" unpackWars="true" />
    <Host name="b.mydomain.com" appBase="bapps" autoDeploy="true" unpackWars="true" />
</Engine>

<Tomcat>/conf/Catalina/a.mydomain.com/ROOT.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="/opt/tomcat/aapps/portal" reloadable="true" path=""></Context>

<Tomcat>/conf/Catalina/b.mydomain.com/ROOT.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="/opt/tomcat/bapps/portal" reloadable="true" path=""></Context>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

by the way, tomcat auto generated a portal.xml in the /conf/Catalina/a.mydomain.com/

Answer (score 0):

What do your workers.properties and context maps look like?